# reactjs url changes on navlink but view doesn't change

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs, react-router

```
<Route path="/dashboard/:id/:screenId/:userId" component={this.Routing}/>
```

Here :id is **Profile**, :screenId is **timeline** or **friends** or **subjects** depending on the particular tab I click and :userId is a particular **tokenId**.

So for one instance, the url looks like

```
dashboard/profile/timeline/abc123 OR dashboard/profile/friends/abc123 etc.
```

But whatever is after the **:id**, the url changes whenever I click on the tabs but the view doesn't change. I have to reload the page to get the view. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i don`t get why you use three URL parameters. I get you need URL parameter for tokens but for rendering different components you don`t need URL parameters.

```
<Route path="/dashboard/profile/timeline/:token" component={...}/>
<Route path="/dashboard/profile/friends/:token" component={...}/>
<Route path="/dashboard/profile/subjects/:token" component={...}/>
```

but maybe for your use case you need three different URL parameters. so maybe more explanation?